# Card probability question

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A 52-card deck is thoroughly shuffled and you are dealt a hand of 13 cards.

(a) If you have one ace, what is the probability that you have a second ace?
(b) If you have the ace of spades, what is the probability that you have a second ace?

Comment: Probability in both parts would be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of hands with exactly one ace is $4{48\choose 12}$.  The number of hands with no aces is ${48\choose 13}$.  So the number of hands with at least one ace is ${52\choose 13}-{48\choose 13}$.  The number of those with more than $1$ ace is: ${52\choose 13}-{48\choose 13}-4{48\choose 12}$.

So the first probability is:
$$\frac{{52\choose 13}-{48\choose 13}-4{48\choose 12}}{{52\choose 13}-{48\choose 13}}$$

You can simplify this by multiplying the numerator and denominator by $\frac{39!13!}{48!}$ to get relatively small numbers.  I got a probability of $\frac{11199}{28996}$, but I wouldn't trust my arithmetic.

There are $51 \choose 12$ hands with the ace of spaces.  If those, there are $48\choose 12$ without another ace.  I'll leave the rest to you.

Comment: In case someone wants to compare with my answer, I got $\frac{1672008}{4523376}$

Answer (score 0):

(a) I interpret the question as asking: Given that you have *at least* one Ace, what is the probability that you have *at least* two Aces. Other interpretations are possible.  We use the language of conditional probabilities, because there are problems with similar structure where that language becomes almost necessary.

Let $A$ be the event "at least one Ace" and let $T$ be the event "at least two Aces." We want $P(T|A)$. Recall that for any events $X$ and $Y$, $P(X|Y)P(Y)=P(X\cap Y)$. So $P(T|A)P(A)=P(T\cap A)$.

First we calculate $P(A)$. It is easier to find the probability of the complementary event "no Aces."
There are $\binom{52}{13}$ hands, all equally likely. The number of no Ace hands is $\binom{48}{13}$. So the probability of a no Ace hand is $\frac{\binom{48}{13}}{\binom{52}{13}}$, and therefore
$$P(A)=1-\frac{\binom{48}{13}}{\binom{52}{13}}.$$ 
Next we find $P(T\cap A)$, which is just $P(T)$.  There are $\binom{4}{2}\binom{48}{11}$ two Ace hands, $\binom{4}{3}\binom{48}{10}$ three Ace hands, and $\binom{4}{4}\binom{48}{9}$ four Ace hands. Add up, divide by $\binom{52}{13}$.

Now we divide to compute $P(T|A)$.  For structural reasons, I would like to give an *inefficient* expression for $P(A)$. This is the probability of one Ace, plus the probability of two Aces, and so on. When we divide to get $P(T|A)$, the $\binom{52}{13}$ cancel, and we get 
$$P(T|A)=\frac{\binom{4}{2}\binom{48}{11}+ \binom{4}{3}\binom{48}{10}+\binom{4}{4}\binom{48}{9}}{\binom{4}{1}\binom{48}{12}+\binom{4}{2}\binom{48}{11}+ \binom{4}{3}\binom{48}{10}+\binom{4}{4}\binom{48}{9}}.$$
Note that the denominator is just the number of hands with $1$ or more Aces, and the numerator is the number of hands with $2$ or more Aces. We have essentially restricted the universe to hands that have at least $1$ Ace.

(b) Let $S$ be the event that our hand includes the $\spadesuit$ Ace, and let $T$ be as before. We want $P(T|S)$, and use $P(T|S)P(S)=P(T\cap S)$.

To find $P(S)$, note that there are $\binom{51}{12}$ hands that contain the $\spadesuit$ Ace. To find $P(T\cap S)$, we count much like in (a). There are $\binom{3}{1}\binom{48}{11}$ hands that contain the $\spadesuit$ Ace and one additional Ace.  There are $\binom{3}{2}\binom{48}{10}$ hands that contain the $\spadesuit$ Ace and two additional Aces. Finally, there are $\binom{3}{3}\binom{48}{9}$ hands that contain the $\spadesuit$ Ace and three additional Aces. Add up, divide by $\binom{52}{13}$. We obtain
$$P(T|S)=\frac{\binom{51}{12}}{\binom{3}{1}\binom{48}{11}+\binom{3}{2}\binom{48}{10}+\binom{3}{3}\binom{48}{9}}.$$

**Remark:** There are computational shortcuts that can and should be used to get numerical answers.  We chose to concentrate on *structure*.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: You are welcome. I have left simplification, computation to you. Note that it turns out that "given Ace of Spades" gives a larger probability than "given at least one Ace."

Comment: Yup sure. I don't so much care for the computation aspect. Like you remarked it's the structure that's important here.

Comment: In the last formula, what you calculated is $1/P(T|S)$?

Comment: The last expression calculates $\Pr(T|S)$.